# Traveling by myself to Delhi, where is a social place to stay?

Tags: backpacking, hostels, new-delhi, socializing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meeting westerners in northern India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11351/meeting-westerners-in-northern-india)

I'm travelling for the first time in January. I'm going to India by myself and Delhi is the first stop. Where is a good place to meet westerners and other backpackers?

I've heard in general travelling is very social and hostels are the best places to meet people. However I've also heard that its harder than most places in India as most people don't stay in hostels. Can anyone give my any advice? I'm 27 and from the UK. Thanks

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.